# What is the Reason why using does not work with uint8_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, using, uint8t

I tried to modernise C++ code to C++11, converting `typedef` statements to `using` statements:

```
class Configuration {
    typedef uint8_t Protocols;
```

Into:

```
class Configuration {
    using Protocols = uint8_t;
```

Where I get this error message from Visual Studio 2012:

```
error C2873: 'Protocols' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

What is the reason why I can not use `using` there?

Comment: Because VS2012 doesn't support `using` correclty. I met a similar problem, but found no real evidence for that.

Comment: Not supported https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: I would suggest a newer compiler, like VS2017

Comment: I should first check this list before asking the question here. :-) A compiler update is sadly not yet possible, but is planed for end of this year.

Comment: @Flovdis in that case I'd wait for the upcoming toolset update for VS2017, it'll have all sorts of goodies, like 2 phase in theory